# Why is my npm not updating to 3.7.2 from 2.14.12?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I have installed node from node's website. By default I have got npm version 2.14.12. Now I want to update npm to 3. I am doing this -

```
$ npm -v
2.14.12 
$ sudo npm install npm@latest -g 
/Users/sudiptasen/.node/bin/npm -> /Users/sudiptasen/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js 
npm@3.7.2 /Users/sudiptasen/.node/lib/node_modules/npm 
$ npm -v
2.14.12
```

Even I have tried, `sudo npm update npm -g`, `sudo npm install npm@3.7.2 -g` but none of these working either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Now this may not work for you because I was already on npm 3.5.3, but try running:

`npm install -g npm` (with `sudo` in front if need be).

By running that I was able to update to 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to create a symlink over my default npm.

```
sudo ln -s /Users/sudiptasen/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm
```